# Tool to search known hash/encryption algo in files in Windows

Tags: ida, encryption, hash-functions, ida-plugin

I am looking for a tool (the best would be an Ida plugin) that can search files in a folder for a known hash (md5/sha1 etc.) and encryption (aes /rsa etc.).

I know an Ida plugin called `FindCrypt2` but this plugin can search only on the file (exe/dll) that is loaded in Ida.

Answer (score 1):

You could run [Yara](https://virustotal.github.io/yara/) with a set of [crypto signatures](https://github.com/Yara-Rules/rules/blob/master/Crypto/crypto_signatures.yar).  Is something like this what you are looking for?